# get values of all variables in class in Python

Tags: python

Say I have a class that has 100 variables in it that each have values. How would I go about getting each of those values without having to know the name of the variable. For example:

```
class Stuff():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
    d = 9.36
    e = "f"
    #and so on...

for i in dir(Stuff):
    print(Stuff.i)    #Does not work but it's what I want to achieve
```

Comment: If you want to get value of members, use inspect.getmembers

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers

Comment: @Pham Thanks. That is exactly what I needed.